# replace quotes using javascript

Tags: javascript

We are building JSON data through user input. It works fine unit unless user input `quotes` as first letter.

My output look like after stringify.

```
{"text":""'><img src=x onerror=alert('1')>"}
```

JSON data if use did not input quotes in first place.

```
{"text":"><img src=x onerror=alert('1')>"}
```

I am trying to replace ""' with " but that did not work for me. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unyddgo3/)

Actual result

```
{"text":""'><img src=x onerror=alert('1')>"}
```

Desired Result

```
{"text":"><img src=x onerror=alert('1')>"}
```

Comment: Can you show your actual result compared to your desired result?

Comment: You do not need to replace anything. The result is correct - you are probably looking at the HTML representation, it actually looks like this `"{"text":"&quot;&#x27;&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(&#x27;1&#x27;)&gt;"}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
var obj = {"text": "&quot;&#x27;&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(&#x27;1&#x27;)&gt;"}
var x = JSON.stringify(obj)

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = x.toString().replace(/["]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the &quot; to " before replace "" with "

Please refer below code to make it work.

```
var obj = {"text": "&quot;&#x27;&gt;&lt;img src=x onerror=alert(&#x27;1&#x27;)&gt;"}
var x = JSON.stringify(obj).replace('&quot;&#x27;','\"\'')

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = x.toString().replace(/""'/,'\"')
```

Also, I have updated your fiddle at [here](https://jsfiddle.net/unyddgo3/5/)